# Is there a open source SVG Windows Explorer preview extension?

Tags: svg, windows-explorer

[Examotion](http://www.examotion.com/index.php?id=31) has a player that can display the image for svg files as a preview in Windows Explorer.  Their product is free, but closed source.  I believe that it also only works with files that actually end in .svg.  I have a need for a similar product that works with files also ending in some other extensions.

Is there an OSS solution that could be modified to suit this need?

Comment: Also, examotion crashes on the first icon that I tried (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Tiger.svg).  I guess its out for other reasons too. :)

Comment: For a format that's so popular, support on Windows Explorer seems shockingly bleak. _Sigh..._ Edit: Examotion no longer exists and SVG Explorer extension is so old, it's broken in Windows 10 version 1709.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mentioned examotion renesis player seems to be the only free explorer extension! It seems to be stable, has good reviews and is working for me (the tiger svg you posted is working as well - maybe that's a different problem with your system).

If support for further extensions is the only problem, I would simply patch your windows registry.
Under

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes

there are entries for .svg and .svgz which declare to use the renesisplayer for thumbnail preview in explorer. you can simply add another key here like .mysvg similar to the existing keys.

Otherwise there are only commercial products like [cadsofttools](http://www.cadsofttools.com/en/products/plugins_for_3d-party_programs.html) which has a svg plugin for irfanview and xnview.

Comment: Interesting... the tiger svg now works.  I have no idea why it was crashing before.

Comment: Hmmm... it has crashed again after a reboot.  This is really weird.

Answer (score 6):

You could try this one as well. It doesn't support the full SVG specification but at least it works. :)

http://code.google.com/p/svg-explorer-extension/

Comment: This extension does not work for me. (Win7 x64)

Comment: @rekire Did you try the [X64 version](https://code.google.com/p/svg-explorer-extension/downloads/list)?

Comment: Curriently I dropped using svg files, but yes I'm pretty sure that I used the x64 version.